# Group by part of attribute in hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model called coverage that looks like this

```
1.9.3p429 :005 > Coverage.new
=> #<Coverage id: nil, postcode: nil, name: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

Here is an example record:

```
1.9.3p429 :006 > Coverage.find(10)
Coverage Load (7.3ms)  SELECT "coverages".* FROM "coverages" WHERE "coverages"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 10]]
=> #<Coverage id: 10, postcode: "N10", name: "N10 - Muswell Hill", created_at: "2013-05-22 14:42:37", updated_at: "2013-05-22 14:42:37">
```

I've got over 300 postcodes and I want to group them by some values I have in this array

```
group = ['N','E','EC','LS','TS']
```

So I would like to do

```
@postcodes = Coverage.all
```

run it through something with the above array to get the following hash

```
@postcode_hash = { 'N' => [ '#Active Record for N1', '#Active Record for N2' ], 'E' => [ '#Active Record for E1', '#Active Record for E2' ] } 
# note: not complete should contain all index from the above array
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use  the **`.group_by{}` method**:

```
@postcodes = Coverage.all
@postcodes_hash = @postcodes.group_by{ |c| c.postcode.gsub(/[0-9]/, '') }
```

Take a look at the `group_by` documentation:
http://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/group_by

There is the explicit version of above:

```
@postcode_hash = {}
group = ['N','E','EC','LS','TS']
group.each{ |code| @postcode_hash[code] = [] }

@postcodes = Coverage.scoped # similar to .all but better
@postcodes.map do |coverage|
  code = coverage.postcode.gsub(/[0-9]/, '') # takes off all the numbers of the postcode
  @postcode_hash[code] << coverage if @postcode_hash[code]
end
```

Comment: Thanks. Gave me plenty to think about too.

Comment: In case you want this done by the database, refer here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#group. It is always a good idea to let the database do as much aggregations as possible.